# Filling the pixels with values of another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, pixel

Say you have two matrices as follows:

```
A = [1 0.2 1; 0.4 0.4 1; 1 0.6 1; 0.9 0.7 1];

B = [33 75 250; 6 34 98; 55 3 4; 153 66 30];
```

Say we want to create a new matrix `C` that contains the values of `B` where `A=1`.

I think in `matlab` we can do the following for this:

`C = B(A==1);`

But, how can I fill the other cells with the original values of `A`, as I think in our case, we will just get a vector with the `B` elements which their corresponding value in `A=1`? And, I want `C` to have the same dimensions of `B` but with the original values of `A` that are **not** equal to `1` instead of having `0` values.

Comment: There is something wrong with your question as you are asking to assign some values of `B` to `C` and then all other values should be those of `B`, which means that in the end `C` will be identical to `B`.

Comment: Yes, I understood that too, but I think he is talking about keeping the dimensions, and filling the other values with zeros.

Comment: Sorry, I have **edited** my question. I meant the original values of `A` not `B`. Is my question more clear now? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
C= A.*(A~=1)+B.*(A==1)
```

Which gives:

```
C =

33.0000    0.2000  250.0000
0.4000    0.4000   98.0000
55.0000    0.6000    4.0000
0.9000    0.7000   30.0000
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the values `0` you have, I want them to be the original values of `A` instead of `0`. This is my main issue here. Do you know how I can go about it? I have made an **edit** to my question if you can see it

Comment: Okay, now it is clear. I changed the solution, it is based on the same principle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just curious. What does `.*` mean? Where can I find more information on it?

Comment: When you add the . in front of an operator like *, /, or ^ it performs the operation elementwise, instead of doing a matrix multiplication. See http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html

Comment: If this answered your question, please be so kind to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`C` will have to be initialized anyways, so let's initialize it to `A` as in `C = A;`. Then, MATLAB allows you to index the left-hand side as in `C(A==1) = B(A==1);` to replace all elements in `C` by those in `B` for which `A == 1`. All other elements will stay the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have made an **edit** to my question if you can see it. Thanks

Comment: Okay, this now makes a lot of sense. I updated my answer as well.